# Logstash csv import - mutate add_field if not empty

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, csv-import

I'm using logstash to import data from csv files into our elasticsearch.

During the import I want to create a new field that has values from two other fields. Here's a snippet of my import:

```
    input {
          file {
            path => "/data/xyz/*.csv"
            start_position => "beginning"
            ignore_older => 0
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
          }
    }

    filter {
        if [path] =~ "csv1" {
            csv {
                  separator => ";"
                  columns =>
                  [
                    "name1",
                    "name2",
                    "name3",
                    "ID"              
                  ]
              }
                mutate {
                  add_field => {
                      "searchfield" => "%{name1} %{name2} %{name3}"
                }
            }
        }

    output {
           if [path] =~ "csv1" {
               elasticsearch {
                  hosts => "localhost"
                  index => "my_index"           
                  document_id => "%{ID}"
               }
           }
    }
}
```

This works as desired but on rows where for example name3 is empty, logstash writes `%{name3}` into the new field. Is there a way to only add the value if it's not empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no other way other than checking if `name3` is present and based on that, build your search field.

```ruby
if [name3] {
  mutate {
    id => "with-name3"
    add_field => { "searchfield" => "%{name1} %{name2} %{name3}" }
  }
} else {
  mutate {
    id => "without-name3"
    add_field => { "searchfield" => "%{name1} %{name2}" }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if I understand your issue right, you obviously want to ship this data to Elasticsearch and want to have a single searchable field. In order to avoid data duplication in your source, you can build a search field by using `copy_to` statement. Your mappings would look as follows:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name1": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchfield" 
        },
        "name2": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchfield" 
        },
        "name3": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchfield" 
        },
        "searchfield": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then you can perfectly run your queries against that field without having duplicates in source.

Update. Basically your logstash.conf would look as follows:

```ruby
input {
  file {
    path => "/data/xyz/*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    ignore_older => 0
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  if [path] =~ "csv1" {
    csv {
      separator => ";"
      columns => ["name1", "name2", "name3", "ID"]
    }
  }
}

output {
  if [path] =~ "csv1" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost"
      index => "my_index"
      document_id => "%{ID}"
    }
  }
}
```

Then create elasticsearch index using the following:

```json
PUT /my_index/
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "name1": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchfield" 
        },
        "name2": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchfield" 
        },
        "name3": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "searchfield" 
        },
        "searchfield": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can run search as follows:

```json
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "searchfield": {
        "query": "your text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. The second solution seems more appropriate for my case. I have however not much experience in elasticsearch yet, so maybe a stupid question. Where do I define the mappings with ``copy_to``  in the config file? Right now we are just creating the mappings with the csv columns. So basically where do I have to place your mapping snippet ? ( Will update my example config for better understanding)

Comment: `copy_to` fragment exists just in Elasticsearch structure for search purpose, it doesn't exist as a source field and Logstash doesn't have to know anything about it. `Logstash` tells what to index, `Elasticsearch` knows how to index it. :) Look for ways to manage Elasticsearch index structures.

Comment: Okay that helps alot. Thank's yor four explanation. :)

Comment: Also, if you take second approach, you no longer have to create `searchfield` and that part can be excluded from your Logstash configuration file :)

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti I've additionally added a better example on how your config should look like based on your update.